# How to keep same file name when updating item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I create model to store image name after uploaded but the image came from Base64 so i converted it to image file and when i create the new image there is no problem but when update or retrieve list of image i got problem
this is my model class

```
    public class User
{


    public int UserId { get; set; }
    private bool Addnew;

    [NotMapped]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsNewItem { get { return Addnew; } set { this.Addnew = value; } }
    public string UserImage
    {
        get { return this.ImageFileName; }
        set { this.ImageFileName = CreateImage(value); }
    }
    private string CreateImage(string value)
    {
        if (IsNewItem)
        {
            return new CreateFile().SetData(this.ImageFileName, value).Image();
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

CreateFile() return the image name after convert it into image file 
if this.ImageFileName in null then return new file name like 204250210368cda45-b8e3-4aea-ad5c-1e224ff16933.png

this is user Controller

```
    public JsonResult Create(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            user.IsNewItem = true;
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
                data = ""
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        return Json(new
        {
            success = false,
            errors = JsonyErrorHelper.MessageToJsonError(ModelState)
        });

    }
```

Comment: User.IsNewItem = true;
                User.ImageFileName = "3333.png";
but always be a null result???

Comment: What does do  and return the CreateFile() function?

Comment: CreateFile()  return the image name after convert it into image file ex:204250210368cda45-b8e3-4aea-ad5c-1e224ff16933.png

Answer (score 0):

By refactoring your model to convert backing fields into auto-properties where appropriate, it looks like your issue is this line:

```cs
new CreateFile().SetData(this.ImageFileName, value).Image()
```

First, `SetData(...)` is taking `ImageFileName` as a parameter after passing a test on `IsNewItem`. This looks like you're saying "This item has no name, but take its name as a parameter.

Without knowing more about what those functions *should* do, this looks a little strange.

Things to look at:

1. Should `SetData(...)` be accepting a potentially null argument for the current `ImageFileName`?
2. Is the method call to `Image()` returning a non-null string in any of your unit tests?

```cs
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string ImageFileName { get; private set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsNewItem { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string UserImage
    {
        get { return this.ImageFileName; }
        set { this.ImageFileName = CreateImage(value); }
    }

    private string CreateImage(string value)
    {
        return 
            IsNewItem
                ? new CreateFile().SetData(this.ImageFileName, value).Image()      
                : value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: not working  IsNewItem is always false so when i go to url:User/Get , to get list of user i face problem

Comment: `IsNewItem` is not mapped to your database, so upon return from your EF context, it should be set to `false` (i.e. the default boolean value). Are you saying that `IsNewItem` is false even after you explicitly set it to true?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. It should be a simple assignment to your POCO. Can you edit your question with the chunk of code in which you assign `IsNewItem` to true, and it doesn't change values?

Comment: Ok i did ,IsNewItem be true in Controller just

Comment: It looks like your controller is taking a `User` as given, and then marking its `IsNewItem` property as true. But then you add the `User` to the database (in which `ImageFileName` is not mapped)  and save. I'm not seeing where `UserImage` is called, or where your database entry would be affected by it even if it were invoked.

Comment: UserImage come from user post

Comment: At which point do you expect `ImageFileName` to be set? By the user? Does the user post know to set the `IsNewItem` to true?